# singleton service error in app.module on ng build

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I am using a singleton service which will be shared across all components, I created a **CoreModule**, having a static class as:

```
static forRoot(config: GlobalServiceConfig): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: CoreModule,
      providers: [
        { provide: GlobalServiceConfig, useValue: config }
      ]
    };
  }
```

in **app.module.ts**

```
export declare var Globals: GlobalServiceConfig;
export const g = Globals;
```

**Globals** dict is created in index.html, value is coming from backend.
now I am using this Globals variable in app.module.ts and provide this initial value to CoreModule.forRoot as:

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    SharedModule,
    LoginModule,
    ShippingModule,
    PaymentModule,
    CoreModule.forRoot(g),
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
```

on first ng build is failing, same with ng serve/watch but only for first time. if i make any changes the app is running fine as expected and getting the initial values also. but not able to build the app. The error states as:

> ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Only
>   initialized variables and constants can be referenced because the
>   value of this variable is needed by the template compiler (position
>   29:20 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol Globals in
>   E:/repos/emtex/mobilepayment/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol g
>   in E:/repos/emtex/mobilepayment/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving
>   symbol AppModule in
>   E:/repos/emtex/mobilepayment/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol
>   AppModule in E:/repos/emtex/mobilepayment/src/app/app.module.ts,
>   resolving symbol AppModule in
>   E:/repos/emtex/mobilepayment/src/app/app.module.ts

**ng --version**

```
@angular/cli: 1.0.0
node: 6.9.1
os: win32 x64
@angular/common: 4.0.0
@angular/compiler: 4.0.0
@angular/core: 4.0.0
@angular/forms: 4.0.0
@angular/http: 4.0.0
@angular/platform-browser: 4.0.0
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.0.0
@angular/router: 4.0.0
@angular/animations: 4.0.0
@angular/cli: 1.0.0
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.0.0
```

Comment: Which version of Angular you're using?

Comment: @angular/cli: 1.0.0
node: 6.9.1
os: win32 x64
@angular/common: 4.0.0
@angular/compiler: 4.0.0
@angular/core: 4.0.0
@angular/forms: 4.0.0
@angular/http: 4.0.0
@angular/platform-browser: 4.0.0
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.0.0
@angular/router: 4.0.0
@angular/animations: 4.0.0
@angular/cli: 1.0.0
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.0.0

Comment: Is your `angular-cli` a beta version (or) rc?

Comment: its final version. @DavidR

Comment: Can you please post your `@NgModule({ providers: ....})` declarations in your static class (if you have anything)

Comment: `@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  declarations: [],
  exports: [],
  providers: [ GlobalService ]
})` @DavidR

Comment: Can you please make it as, `@NgModule({ imports: [CommonModule, SharedModule, SharedModule.forRoot()], declarations: [], exports: [], providers: [ GlobalService ] })` and try??

Comment: @DavidR Can't use this in SharedModule, as this is a singleton service, sharing same instance of service in every module, and I am using sharedModule in many other modules, as per documentation **Do not specify app-wide singleton providers in a shared module.** [See Here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#core-module)

Comment: I think the error is clear, your `g` variable is not initialized and cannot be resolved statically. you said `g` is coming from backend, it's best to handle this with a promise or an observable.

Answer (score 2):

The error is clear, your `g` variable is not initialized, therefor it cannot be resolved statically. You said `g` is coming from backend but there is no way for angular to know when `g` is resolved (value is returned from backend)

You can handle this with a promise or an observable where you do not bootstrap until that value comes back.

Or you can change your provider to `useFactory` and change `g` to a promise or observable then in your service factory wait for `g` to be resolved. See angular doc for factory-provider here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#factory-provider